# How to attach effects to the F in Resource[F, A] without using A?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

Given a `Resource[F, A]`, what is the most idiomatic way to attach effects (e.g. metrics, logging errors) to `F` without using `A` (i.e. `.use`)?

I can easily do that with a `F[A]` but I depend on an API that specifically returns a `Resource[F, A]` to make sure that `A` will be released correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I'd use `Resource.liftF` and `<*`. For example:

```
import cats.effect.{ IO, Resource }
import cats.syntax.apply._
import scala.io.Source

val src = Resource.fromAutoCloseable(IO(Source.fromFile("build.sbt")))
val log = IO(println("opening file"))

val loggedSrc = src <* Resource.liftF(log)
```

And then:

```
scala> val program = loggedSrc.use(s => IO(println(s.mkString)))
program: cats.effect.IO[Unit] = IO$201584418

scala> program.unsafeRunSync
opening file
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.2.0"
```

In general you'd have the same approach you'd use in `F`, but lifted into `Resource[F, _]` with `Resource.liftF`.

Comment: Nice. I was actually close but got sidetracked by Intellij not being able to compile such code... Thanks!

Comment: productL doesn't exist on Resource class instance

Comment: Apply[Resource[IO, ?]].productL(src)(Resource.liftF(log))